# Mock buildin class AWS Logs client builder

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I am trying to Mock and use a AWS buildin class. But continuous getting different error.

While I am testing a entire method I was able to mock all other but when it comes to credentials formation using when then too throws exception.

```
 BasicAWSCredentials basic = new BasicAWSCredentials(clientToken, clientSecret);
  //Forming AWSLogs
 AWSLogs awsLogsClient = AWSLogsClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(basic))
            .withRegion(region)
            .build();

 DescribeLogStreamsRequest logStreamsRequest = new 
 DescribeLogStreamsRequest().withLogGroupName("SomeLogGroupName");

 //This is where I am getting error while mocking. But this same exectes properly while running with actual credentilas. But while mocking it fails       
 DescribeLogStreamsResult describeLogStreamsResult = awsLogsClient.describeLogStreams(logStreamsRequest);
```

Error message while executing Junit mockito test.

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.logs.model.UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AWSLogs; Status Code: 400; Error Code: UnrecognizedClientException; Request ID:
```

So will be helpful if Mockito test was created only for above code. I am completely new to Mockito

Answer (score 0):

Since you are writing a unit test you don't want to make the real http call using the `awsLogsClient`, instead you want to create a mock for that client so that you can control what response you get back. By doing so you can test you code for success and fail cases. Another good thing with this is that your unit test will execute a lot faster and without a Internet connection.

I would start by mocking the interface:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/logs/AWSLogs.html

But you will need some mechanism to inject this dependency to your production code.